# JSON parsing error in script text ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, mechanize, string-parsing

I am trying to get json parsed from the script text that contains stores data.It is inside the page http://www.buildbase.co.uk/storefinder . The script text which i am working around is http://pastebin.com/embed_js/3cnewiSh and my code is as follows:

```
stores_url = "http://www.buildbase.co.uk/storefinder"
mechanize = Mechanize.new
stores_page = mechanize.get(stores_url)
stores_script_txt = stores_page.search("//script[contains(text(), 'storeLocator.initialize(')]")[0].text
stores_jsons = stores_script_txt.split("storeLocator.initialize( $.parseJSON('{\\\"all\\\":")[-1].split(",\\\"selected\\\":0}') ,\tfalse);\n        });")[0]
puts stores_jsons
stores_result = JSON.parse(stores_jsons)
```

The JSON.parse gives me the error as:

```
from /home/private/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
from /home/private/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
from (irb):240
from /home/private/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I don't know where i am going wrong because the JSON string seems valid to me.

Comment: Can you add a simple `puts stores_jsons` before the `stores_result =` line so we can see the actual JSON it's trying to parse?

Comment: @PaulEllsworth done now.

Comment: @PaulEllsworth , Hi paul i corrected one more mistake when trying to get json string in stores_jsons. Can you please see?

Comment: I think @PaulEllsworth meant to run the code with the `puts` statement and then copy the output to your answer.

Comment: @PaulEllsworth Actually i can't do it because it will exceed the characters limit of the question.

Comment: Can you provide a shortened version of the json?  Or use something like pastebin and link to it (is that allowed on stackoverflow? not 100% sure, ha).

Comment: @PaulEllsworth done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple problems.  First, the text you were getting wasn't properly formatted in that it used \" instead of quotes, etc.

Second, it had HTML tags in it, which included quotes, which broke the quoting in the actual JSON.  I grabbed a snippet that just strips out the tags.

I don't know how much of the data you need, but this code does work.  I am also not sure how robust it is (e.g., I just substituted `"` for any `\"`)

```
require 'mechanize'
stores_url = "http://www.buildbase.co.uk/storefinder"
mechanize = Mechanize.new
stores_page = mechanize.get(stores_url)
stores_script_txt = stores_page.search("//script[contains(text(), 'storeLocator.initialize(')]")[0].text
stores_jsons = stores_script_txt.split("storeLocator.initialize( $.parseJSON('{\\\"all\\\":")[-1].split(",\\\"selected\\\":0}') ,\tfalse);\n        });")[0]
stores_jsons = stores_jsons.gsub('\"', '"').gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, '').gsub(/\n\n+/, "\n").gsub(/^\n|\n$/, '')
stores_result = JSON.parse(stores_jsons)
```